# Getting more information about a transformer

Tags: transformer, identification, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to figure out more information about a small transformer on a old board that we are reverse engineering, can someone give me some advices about how can we reverse engineer this transformer? Do the numbers on it represent something?

```
4783 
6610741
```

[image]

Comment: The top number is almost certainly a date code (e.g., 47th week of 1983), which jibes with the evident level of PCB technology. The other number is going to be an in-house (proprietary) part number used by the original manufacturer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers aren't going to help you.  Remove the unit from the board, and you can probe around with a ohmmeter to figure out what is connected to what and what the DC resistance of each coil is.  Then inject a sine wave of a few volts into one of the windings, and measure the open circuit voltage of the other windings to find the turns ratio.  Then you can load individual outputs with known resistances to see how the voltage drops to get some idea of impedance.

From context, you can hopefully get some idea of what the transformer is intended to do.  From the small size and apparent lack of isolation (although we can't be sure from this picture), it is probably not handling wall power.  It could be a audio transformer, or maybe something for a switching power supply, but that is less likely if this was really built in 1983.  It seems too big for a pulse transformer.

I'd start with using 1 kHz for the AC test signal and see where that leads.  1 kHz is a good frequency for probing audio transformers.